# Sound problem ASUS x55u

Tags: 16.04, sound, asus

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my ASUS X555U, but I can't have any sound.

I appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: What sound card do you have?

Comment: lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, as a I believe the issue here, is actually pretty simple to fix. Have you tried `pulseaudio -k`? Pulseaudio is basically a proxy for your sound systems on linux and the `-k` option will "kill an already running PulseAudio daemon"(From man).

Comment: I've tried but I'm still without sound, thanks

Comment: @epelaezr I'm sure you probably tried this already but what about `sudo alsa force-reload`?

Comment: Thanks again,  I did it, but still can't hear anything.

Comment: Have you checked your sound settings through the GUI?

Comment: Yes, shows speakers, internal audio, but nothing appears to be wrong.

Comment: Last try here `sudo apt-get install alsa-utils --reinstall `.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, guess what, Windows!

I just made and update/upgrade and now I have sound.

But when I have to start session windows (with normal sound) and after that start session in Ubuntu I don't have any sound.

I have to restart mi laptop and start session in Ubuntu, and have normal sound.

Strange, not ideal but fixed.

Thanks to all who gave their opinions and help.